# Problem installing the WWDR Apple Certificate on Keychain

Tags: iphone, osx-snow-leopard, certificate

I'm not sure if this is a beginner's question, so excuse me if it is.

I can't install the WWDR Apple certificate. I downloaded but then on keychain it tells me the following:
(It's in spanish so I'm translating as good as I can)

"The "Root System" keychain cannot be modified."
"To change if a root certificate is of trust or not, open the Keychain and modify the trust settings. New root certificates must be added to the startup session of the current user, or to the keychain system if they have to be shared by all users of this computer"

How can I solve this?

Update: I actually can't install a custom certificate I made and submitted for approval (approved) I downloaded it but I can't install it! I have the same error popping up.

This is the error: 
[image]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you open the Keychain Access app you should see on the left a list of keychains. If you select the 'login' keychain, can you drag the certificate in then?

Comment: Okay It works. But The problem was that it didn't even asked me to install it on the login keychain. It just assumed I wanted to install it on the Root System Keychain. Thank you!